# $htmlOptions is not working in CHtml::dropDownList Yii

Tags: php, yii, yii-chtml

I have this implementation of CHtml:

```
<?=CHtml::dropDownList('id_sistema', $Proveedor[0]['id_sistema'],CHtml::listData(Sistemas::model()->findAll(),'sistema_id', 'sistema_nombre'),array('empty' => 'Selecciona un sistema...'),array('class'=>'form-control chosen-select'));?>
```

But is so weird that is not recognizing the 'form-control' css class. I have read several times the documentation and I can not find de issue.

I someone have any idea, I will appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried this one?

```
<?=CHtml::dropDownList('id_sistema', $Proveedor[0]['id_sistema'],CHtml::listData(Sistemas::model()->findAll(),'sistema_id', 'sistema_nombre'),array('empty' => 'Selecciona un sistema...', 'class'=>'form-control chosen-select'));?>
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/48/by-example-chtml/#hh5

Html Options is on the 4th parameter of the dropDownList

Comment: You are right, the class was the fourth parameter! thank you!